# 'this' in as3 in Fla Timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have written the below code in timeline .

```
    function chk():void
{

}

this["temp"]=chk;

                          /*   output   */
trace(this.chk);      //function Function() {}


trace(chk);          //function Function() {}

trace(this.temp)   //function Function() {}

trace(temp)        // Access of undefined property temp.
```

And I have given the output what I got . 
My doubt is why this.temp is not same as temp , where this.chk is same as chk

Answer (score 1):

The variable `temp` is not available at compilation time. So a compiler push an error. But at runtime your programm execute this code `this["temp"]=chk;` and the variable `temp` becomes available.

Comment: No .. But for trace(this.temp) its giving output

Comment: Because `MainTimeline` class is dynamic. So if you explicitly show him that `temp` is a property of a dynamic object (write `this.property`) then the compiler doesn't check availability of this property. For an example you can `trace(obj.fakeProperty)`, where `obj` is an instance of the `Object` class. But if you don't show for the compiler that `temp` is the property of the dynamic class, it will push an error.